# Share files between instances on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, filesystems, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have a Python application with different modules using different types of servers. I'd like to share files between these modules. 
I've tried doing that by mounting Cloud Storage as a directory but performance is very slow.
Is there another way on GCP to use files in read + write mode on several instances simultaneously?

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing the entire picture, but have you tried the [Official Python API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) for Google Cloud Storage? Perhaps your application could send information using [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) instead of sharing files?

Comment: Finally the solution was quite straight to the point. I used a SIngle Node File Server : https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/singlefs?project=verteego-is